# Why does Postgres perform only sequential scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sequence

I am running some queries on my table in postgres.My table consist of data from 2010 to 2020 around 1.000.000 rows.Whichever query i test,postgres only performs sequential scan.
For example:
my data looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.timestamppsql
(
    id1 double precision,
    id6 double precision,
    id7 double precision,
    id8 double precision,
    id9 double precision,
    id10 double precision,
    id11 double precision,
    id12 double precision,
    id13 double precision,
    c14 text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id15 double precision,
    id16 double precision,
    id17 double precision,
    id18 double precision,
    id19 double precision,
    id20 double precision,
    id21 double precision,
    id22 double precision,
    id23 double precision,
    timestamp1 timestamp without time zone,
    timestamp2 timestamp without time zone
)
```

```
explain (analyze, buffers,format text) select id13 from timestamppsql where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' and timestamp1<='2010-01-02 00:05:00'
```

Explain Analyze

```
    "Gather  (cost=1000.00..39459.55 rows=251 width=8) (actual time=0.171..166.399 rows=289 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  Buffers: shared hit=28224"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on timestamppsql  (cost=0.00..38434.45 rows=148 width=8) (actual time=78.040..157.282 rows=144 loops=2)"
"        Filter: ((timestamp1 >= '2010-01-01 00:05:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (timestamp1 <= '2010-01-02 00:05:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 578448"
"        Buffers: shared hit=28224"
"Planning Time: 0.050 ms"
"Execution Time: 166.429 ms"
```

This query affects only 290 rows so it should use an index scan.I have used a lot of queries but everytime postgres performs only sequential scan.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - no screen shots please. Make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: do you have an index with timestamp1 at first position(at least containing id13 and timestamp1), are the statistics up to date?

Comment: Your image does not seem to show the complete execution plan. There is a `Gather` but no parallelism.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for you suggestion!I edited the question

Comment: @turo .I edited the question with the type of data.What do you mean by statistics are up to date?

Comment: I see no index at all, and having an index doesn't mean it will be used. Analyse gathers info over table data(the statistics) so the planner can make an educated guess whats the bast way to retrieve the data

Comment: @turo sorry but can you explain to me what do you mean by index?

Comment: So what could postgres do without any index? google CREATE INDEX

Comment: @turo Thank you!Does index have anything to do with sequential scan ?

Comment: With the right index created the planner will decide  to make an index scan(if the statistics are up to date)

Comment: @turo Thank you!i need to ask you one more thing.How can i found the ideal index for my table?which are the parameters I should check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229989/discussion-between-turo-and-xaroulis-gekas).